# Jquery delay between two fade toggle effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am showing and displaying two divs using `Jquery`

The code is

```
var show_hide = function () {
    $("#extravagents_label").fadeToggle(function () {
        $("#liquid.liquidContanier").fadeToggle().delay(1500);
    });
}

setInterval(show_hide, 1500);
```

but there is problem. it is not doing the job properly. It should display the other div when one is completely hidden.  Kindly visit **203.81.193.2/jsvt/**. There are the icons and the text under the main slider that is displaying and hiding.

Comment: You say "it is not doing the job properly," but don't tell us what "properly" actually means. Also: it's important to reduce your code to a minimum of HTML and CSS as well as JavaScript, and post it in the question -- your external website may vanish at any time, rendering this question useless for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be careful with timings and `setInterval` it can mess things up pretty bad.

If timings are the problem:

```
var show_hide = function () {
    $("#extravagents_label").fadeToggle(callblack);
}

var callblack = function () {
    $("#liquid.liquidContanier").fadeToggle()
        .delay(1500).queue(show_hide);
}
```

Hope this helps, still not sure what you're after

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**jQuery**:

```
function show_hide() {
 $('#extravagents_label').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
 $("#liquid .liquidContanier").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
   //don't forgot to use space between id and it's child class
}

setInterval(show_hide,4000);
           //this timing should be total timing values of the show_hide function
```

guessing your **css** should be like:

```
#extravagents_label { display:block; }
#liquid .liquidContanier { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTbzd/) for you that modifies your code somewhat. Basically your interval is firing every 1.5 seconds whilst you're also delaying the fadeToggle on the second element. Because you can't time how long it's going to take jQuery to fade the elements in and out, the callback handles it for you.

```
var show_hide = function () {
    $("#extravagents_label").fadeToggle(function () {
        $(this).fadeToggle();
        $("#liquid.liquidContanier").fadeToggle(function () {
            $(this).fadeToggle();
            show_hide();
        });
    });
}

setTimeout(show_hide, 1500);
```